# Why browser.search.defaulturl is not present in about:config file?

Tags: firefox

Why browser.search.defaulturl is not present in about:config file?

I want to change default searchbox engine in firefox.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

In `Firefox 3.5.8` it is represented by `browser.search.defaultenginename` which points to engine name and not URL ofcourse. If you want to change the engine, click on the down arrow button at start of Search box and you will have different options to choose